# how is Etherscan decoding transactions whose contract address has no available ABI?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, abi

Hi I was wondering how Etherscan was able to decode this transaction even though the contract address doesn't appear to have any ABI
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x60ec6dbe05abb9bde9de3963ff6df1c600f041b1845f4735871d127d22953ac9

Comment: There's a public database of known function selector at 4byte.directory. It is likely Etherscan has its own database from the verified contracts. If you search you'll find there's duplicated selectors, for example there are three functions that have the same selector `0x70a08231`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what part of the transaction you're referring:

1. **Contract function name**

There is a database of known signatures for the contract function names called 4bytes.directory. In particular, [this signature 0x8119c065](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x8119c065) corresponds call of function `swap` without arguments.

2. **Tokens involved into the transaction**

This information can be inferred via the [events produced by the transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x60ec6dbe05abb9bde9de3963ff6df1c600f041b1845f4735871d127d22953ac9#eventlog). It's possible to obtain them from the transaction receipt.

Comment: Thanks man ! the help is super appreciated.                                                                                          So finding the common signatures you can decode the sub transactions (in this case they were multiple back to back swap) thus be able to know the token involved (by getting their contract adresses)